# Creating a new empty directory folder with the record id number on the desktop for each record added with the form in Django

Tags: django

First of all, my english is not very good, sorry for that.

I only have one field in my model. I want to create an empty directory folder on the desktop while creating a record using the form. Since I am new to Django, I would be grateful if you could write the complete codes. Thank you very much in advance.

MODELS.PY

```
class DosyaBilgileri(models.Model):
sahisAdi = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Şahıs Adı')

def __str__(self):
    return self.sahisAdi


def delilIndex(request):
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def delilIndex(request): 

dosyaEkleFormu = DosyaBilgileriModelForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
if dosyaEkleFormu.is_valid():
    dosyaEkleFormuD = dosyaEkleFormu.save(commit=False)
    dosyaEkleFormuD.save()
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Dosya ekleme işlemi başarıyla tamamlandı.')
    return redirect('delilIndex')


return render(request, 'delil/index.html', {'dosyaEkleFormu':dosyaEkleFormu })
```

Comment: Why do you want to save it on the desktop? Can you explain your use case here? Normally you'd want to save the data in a database

Comment: I want each record to have its own folder on the desktop because I can copy some files that I do not want to save to the database into this folder myself. I would be glad if you could help with something like this.